# function iterates through loop and works once but never again

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I'm calling a Titanium modal window to open and then run a function which loops through some data like so;

Window 1:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'window2.js'
    modal: 1
});
win.open();
```

Window 2: (called from window 1)

```
win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

function doLoop() {
    Ti.API.info('doLoop fn called');
    // I've tracked the issue down to here
    var m = 0;
    for(var i in list) { m++; }

    Ti.API.info(m);
    Ti.API.info('finished');
}

win.addEventListener('open', function() {
    // list is dynamically generated and passed through successfully from window1.js
    doLoop();
});
```

doLoop() is called successfully each time and list is called each time successfully.

The first time run it works perfectly. The second(any that isn't first) time run it takes time to pause and run the the loop but m is never incremented? After the pause for the loop outputs 'finished'.

Any ideas?

```
function buildMediaItemsSelectionTable() {
    var mediaCount = 0, i;

    for(i in mediaItemsSelectionList[0]) { mediaCount++; }

    for(i=0,l=mediaCount;i<l;i++) {
        addMediaItemsSelectionSongsRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it helps the list is stored in Ti.App.Properties.getList('list'); so the function doLoop() has access to it every time.

Comment: JSON object, I believe about 3 deep with more objects but I'm only after the fist depth

Comment: okay much better updated code above. I have verified that the list is there each time with the Titanium equivalent `Ti.API.info(list)` and it does exist and is run through that loop but the second loop never runs because the first never increments

Comment: I assure you the list is never empty. It wouldn't run properly the first time if not. I've placed several tests in and limited it down the first loop on the second time as the issue. I'm more wondering if that loop is caching and not running the second time or something similar?

Comment: yes, and yes, I've even verified that `mediaItemsSelectionList[0] === mediaItemsSelectionList[0]` where the it's checking to see if the cached list is the exact same as the dynamic version which is true each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues I see here.

First, the problems with your `buildMediaItemsSelectionTable()` function

1. Your for..in loop might catch object properties you don't
2. There's no need for the double loop

Here's those modifications in place

```
function buildMediaItemsSelectionTable()
{
  var i = 0, p;

  for ( p in mediaItemsSelectionList[0] )
  {
    if ( mediaItemsSelectionList[0].hasOwnProperty( p ) )
    {
      addMediaItemsSelectionSongsRow( i++ );
    }
  }
}
```

The other issue is one I'm having to guess at since you didn't provide enough code.  I'm assuming that you're passing `list` to the modal with Titanium's variable forwarding.  Perhaps something like this?

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:   'window2.js'
  , modal: 1
  , list:  [1,2,3]
});
```

And something has to repeatedly open the modal, right?  Maybe a button

```
var button = Ti.UI.createButton( {title: 'Modal'} );
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add( button );

button.addEventListener( 'click', function()
{
  win.open();
});
```

But according to your description, `list` changes so let's make a random list generator and plug it in to our page so the entire thing looks like this

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url:   'window2.js'
  , modal: 1
  , list:  randomList()
});

var button = Ti.UI.createButton( {title: 'Modal'} );
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add( button );

button.addEventListener( 'click', function()
{
  win.open();
});

function randomList()
{
  // Random return an array with 3, 5, or 7 items
  return [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]][Math.floor(Math.random()*2)];
}
```

What's wrong here?  `randomList()` is only called once, regardless of how many times you open the modal.  Even if window1 is part of a nav or tab group, the code that creates the modal window doesn't re-execute under any circumstances.

If you want a new list to be forwarded to the modal every time, you'll have to generate it fresh every time

```
button.addEventListener( 'click', function()
{
  win.list = randomList();
  win.open();
});
```

Comment: None of these answers were correct but Peter you're right I should have posted more code. It's solved now however and it's what you posted above that got me to my solution or at least a different way of thinking about it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your '}' is in the wrong place.  Right now you have a loop with a single (likely unintended) side effect - m counts up to the length of the list and then there is a call to API.info with the length of list.

You probably want :

```
function doLoop() {
    Ti.API.info('doLoop fn called');
    // I've tracked the issue down to here
    var m = 0;
    for(var i in list) { 
        m++;

       Ti.API.info(m);
       Ti.API.info('finished');
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you. In most cases I would completely agree however in this case I'm using `m` to get the length of an object and then another for loop is called in the original way `for(i=0;i<m;i++)` which runs next. It works perfect the first time but then the second loop doesn't run every time after because `m` never gets setup again.